# Неправильно определяются введенные данные

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь сделать калькулятор. Почему когда пишу числа с плавающей точкой, точку принимает как оператор и выводит -1(default)?

```
      public double operator(String a, String b, String op) {
        switch (op) {
        case "+":

            return Double.valueOf(a) + Double.valueOf(b);
        case "-":
            return Double.valueOf(a) - Double.valueOf(b);
        case "/":
            return Double.valueOf(a) / Double.valueOf(b);
        case "*":
            return Double.valueOf(a) * Double.valueOf(b);
        default:
            return -1;
          }
    }

    public void clickEquals() {
    String rezultat;
    String[] operation = display.split(Pattern.quote(currentOperation));
    Double result = operator(operation[0], operation[1], currentOperation);

    if ((result * 10) % 10 == 0) {
        rezultat = String.valueOf(result);
        txtv.setText(display + "=" + rezultat.substring(0, rezultat.length() 
      - 2));

    }
   else {
        txtv.setText(display + "=" + String.valueOf(result));

        }
```

Comment: Я использую свои экстрасенсорные способности и угадываю- если у вас пришла не цифра, вы используете метод `operator`, который и по `default` ветке switch'a возвращает вам `-1`.

Comment: Я нашла ошибку,с утра не могла найти ,как только опубликовала вопрос вспомнила.

Comment: Осталось только оформить ее как ответ к этому вопросу.

Comment: <Button
            android:id="@+id/btndot"   
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
            android:layout_height="70dp"   
            android:layout_weight="1"   
            android:elevation="0dp"   
            android:onClick="clickNumber" //здесь я по ошибке сделала вызов метода  
   операторов ,поэтому как оператор принималась точка.   
            android:text="." />

Comment: На будущее: не нужно писать весь текст вопроса в заголовок, а в тексте только код.